# Google Maps API - How to remove location spikes

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, android-location

I am trying to create a location tracking app, in which mobile application sends current lat-long and timestamp in every 10 seconds.
it works fine when the mobile device is moving.

but when the mobile device is still for sometime ~ 1-min, it starts sending location of different places which results in location spikes and decreases the location accuracy and other factors depending on it,
is there any way i can minimise or nullify those fake locations, i didn't find any solution for mobile end as well.

P.S. i, am using android app to send information to firebase and then retrieving it from there on browser

Here is the sample code to draw path

```
/* 
history contains all the location traces in lat-long
*/
var linePath = [];
for (var i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
    var tempLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(history[i]['lat'], history[i]['long']);
    linePath.push(tempLatLng);
}
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: linePath,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#669DF6',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 6
});

line.setMap(map)
```

[spikes when device is still](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwn9X.png)

[correct location when device is moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAa4h.png)

Comment: hey @anuj jain, have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The effect you're seeing is almost certainly just the device GPS and location services being inaccurate.  It's very common, especially indoors.

If you don't want to record these inaccurate readings, you will have to detect them on your own, or find a library that can smooth out the series of readings.  As far as I know, there is no API provided by Google Maps that will do this for you.